# Can't update node globally with nvm?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I want to upgrade node to v8.3 globally. I'm working on the latest OSX and using v0.33.0 of nvm.

I can upgrade successfully in one bash shell:

```
$ which node
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.0/bin/node
$ nvm install 8.3 --reinstall-packages-from=8.1
v8.3.0 is already installed.
Now using node v8.3.0 (npm v5.3.0)
Reinstalling global packages from v8.1.4...
Linking global packages from v8.1.4...
$ node -v
```

But then if I open a new shell, it's still pointing at the old version:

```
$ which node
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.0/bin/node
$ node -v
v8.1.0
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't see anything in my bash profile pointing to the older version.

Comment: just set the alias to the proper version `nvm alias default v8.3.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also set your default node version, like this:

```
nvm alias default 8.3.0
```

This should set your version moving forward. Credit: 
https://eric.blog/2016/08/23/set-default-node-version-with-nvm/